# .Net Windows Forms ListView OwnerDraw LargeImageList leak

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I'm ownerdrawing .Net Windows Forms ListView control and see a very strange bug/behavior when I need to draw an image from the associated LargeImageList.

When the View type is a type where LargeImageList is used (Tile, LargeIcon, etc.), I draw item images from the LargeImageList. At that condition, I see a huge memory increase and when you try to scroll ListView this becomes more obvious as you see a jerky scroll as well. This same thing does not happen when the same code uses SmallImageList which is simply like this :

```
Image MyImage = this.LargeImageList.Images[MyIndex];
e.Graphics.DrawImage(MyImage,MyLocation);
```

This is reproducable under XP and 7 according to my tests. Is this a known bug, any workaround?

Regards,

Özden

Answer (score 3):

Although I still think this is a bug, I found a workaround. If you draw using **ImageList.Draw** instead of **e.Graphics.DrawImage** this problem seems to go away.

Answer (score 1):

How are you managing the invalidated drawing area? As you are saying, looks like you are "overdrawing" the control, I mean, drawing even when it is not necessary.

Comment: Starting from .Net 2, ListView provides ownerdraw feature and raises events such as DrawItem, DrawSubItem, etc. These events, I suppose, are raised for each item when they need to be redrawn. I do not override the controls WNDProc to catch the WM_PAINT or any other thing.